# fxruby Progressbar width

Tags: ruby, fxruby

I don't know if I'm getting the whole documentation totally wrong but there is an issue I'm dealing with since two days and I just don't get what I'm doing wrong. I'm using fxruby to built a small GUI, and I need a progressbar within that. When I initialize it with no parameters its just ridiculously small, so I tried to use the barSize option (which is responsible for the width, at least the documentation says so). This is my source code:

```
require 'fox16'
require 'pp'

include Fox

class Test < FXMainWindow
  def initialize(app)
    super(app, "Test")

    hFrame1 = FXHorizontalFrame.new(self)

    @progBar = FXProgressBar.new(hFrame1)
    pp @progBar.barSize
    @progBar.barSize=100
    @progBar.setTotal(10)
    @progBar.setProgress(5)
    pp @progBar.barSize


    def create
      super
      show(PLACEMENT_SCREEN)
    end

  end
end

FXApp.new do |app|
    Test.new(app)
    app.create
    app.run
end
```

But this is what it looks like:

[image](https://imgur.com/Mx7OmyJ)

So obviously the height gets changed. Obviously I also tried things like

```
:width => 150
```

in the constructor but it did not work at all. Seems like I'm just to stupid for fxruby. Could anyone point me to the right way please?

Comment: Not sure if barSize is for width, have you tried playing around with `progress` as mentioned here: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/fxruby/Fox%2FFXProgressBar:progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn about layout parameters.  Try this modification of your `Test` class and I think you will know where to go from there:

```
class Test < FXMainWindow
  def initialize(app)
    super(app, "Test", :width => 200, :height => 100)

    hFrame1 = FXHorizontalFrame.new(self, LAYOUT_FILL)

    @progBar = FXProgressBar.new(hFrame1, :opts => LAYOUT_FILL_X)
    pp @progBar.barSize
    @progBar.barSize=10
    @progBar.setTotal(10)
    @progBar.setProgress(5)
    pp @progBar.barSize


    def create
      super
      show(PLACEMENT_SCREEN)
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!